# pandas_gbq unable to attach label to bigquery job

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I've tried to attach labels to bigquery jobs, this should work via Bigquery API like:

```
df = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, dialect='standard', configuration=query_config)

query_config = {
        "query": {
            "labels": {
                "label": "labelName"
            }
        }
    }
```

but it won't attach labels at all.

While googles bigquery connector works flawlessly:

```
df = client.query(sql, job_config=query_config, project=project_id).to_dataframe()

query_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    labels={
        'label': 'labelName'
    }
)
```

Am I misreading the documentaion of the BigQuery API?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look at the structure of the REST request: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#queryrequest

The `labels` field should not be inside the `query` field:

```
config = {
    "labels": {
       "label": "labelName"
    }
}

df = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, dialect='standard', configuration=config)
```